# A way to use all the unqualified names in a C++0x enum class?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, using-declaration

The new C++ (C++0x or C++11) has an new kind of enum, an "enum class" where the names are scoped to the enum (among other things).

```
enum class E {
    VAL1, VAL2
};

void fun() {
    E e = E::VAL1;  // Qualified name
}
```

I'm wondering, however, if I can selectively use the unqualified name in a certain scope.  Something like:

```
void fun() {
    using E::*;
    E e = VAL1;
    switch (e) {
        case VAL2: ...
```

I see I can write `using E::VAL1` and get one value.  But I don't want to do that for every value of a larger enum.

Comment: If I may ask, what compiler are you using?  A bug report for being able to 'using E::Val1;' is in order.

Comment: I missed this comment years ago. It was, and still is, clang. Now version 4.0.

Comment: Is clang4 still not getting this?  Surprising.  I was/am working gcc - now 4.8.  This works there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to do this in C++11. Just in case you are not aware of it - you get the `E::Val1` notation even for an unscoped enumeration. For such an enumeration, you have `Val1` accessible with and without the use of `E::`.

But you cannot take a scoped enumeration and selectively make all its enumerators visible in a given scope. It should also be noted that you can *not* write `using E::Val1`. The spec explicitly forbids this, your compiler just doesn't reject it yet.

Comment: For the curious, §7.3.3/7 reads "A using-declaration shall not name a scoped enumerator."

Answer (score 1):

This is also something I happen to want, but haven't gotten around to trying to solve. Here's an <s>untested</s> solution. **EDIT:** I tried it out and it works great! This is my very first C++11 utility macro. Also I added a one-past-the-end enumerator to help extend it to "derived" enumerations.

```
#define IMPORTABLE_ENUM( TYPENAME, ... ) \
\
struct import_ ## TYPENAME { \
    enum TYPENAME { \
        __VA_ARGS__ \
    }; \
}; \
\
typedef import_ ## TYPENAME :: TYPENAME TYPENAME;
```

This cannot be imported into a block scope, but defines a base class `import_duck` to bring the enumerators into a class. Usage:

```
IMPORTABLE_ENUM ( duck, huey, dewey, louie )

duck d = duck::dewey; // can't use unscoped enumerators here

struct duck_madness : private import_duck { // but inside a derived class
    duck who_did_it() { return huey; } // qualification is unnecessary
}
```

And since there is only one `enum` type even among derived classes, no `static_cast` is ever required.