# Equivalent of "using namespace X" for scoped enumerations?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

I am using a scoped enum to enumerate states in some state machine that I'm implementing. For example, let's say something like:

```
enum class CatState
{
    sleeping,
    napping,
    resting
};
```

In my cpp file where I define a state transition table, I would like to use something equivalent to `using namespace X` so that I don't need to prefix all my state names with `CatState::`. In other words, I'd like to use `sleeping` instead of `CatState::sleeping`. My transition table has quite a few columns, so avoiding the `CatState::` prefix would keep things more compact and readable.

So, is there a way to avoid having to type `CatState::` all the time?

---

<sup>Yeah, yeah, I'm already aware of the pitfalls of `using namespace`. If there's an equivalent for strongly-typed enums, I promise to only use it inside a limited scope in my cpp implementation file, and not for evil.</sup>

Comment: Do you really need an `enum class`, or would an `enum` do?

Comment: It originally was a plain `enum`, but I'm transitioning my code to use C++11 features. I like the idea of stronger type safety with `enum class`.

Comment: See: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1099r2.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> So, is there a way to avoid having to type `CatState::` all the time?

Not before C++20. Just as there's no equivalent for having to type `ClassName::` for static class members. You can't say `using typename ClassName` and then get at the internals. The same goes for strongly typed `enum`s.

C++20 adds the `using enum X` syntax, which does what it looks like.

You can of course not use `enum class` syntax, just using regular `enum`s. But then you lose strong typing.

It should be noted that one of the reasons for using ALL_CAPS for weakly typed enums was to avoid name conflicts. Once we have full scoping and strong typing, the name of an enum is uniquely identified and cannot conflict with other names. Being able to bring those names into namespace scope would reintroduce this problem. So you would likely want to use ALL_CAPS again to help disambiguate the names.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I was imagining the strong enum to be something like a namespace, but thinking about it as a (somewhat) class makes more sense now.

Comment: As of C++20 via paper p1099r4 this will no longer be the case, thankfully.

Comment: To each their own, but I personally don't like the ALL_CAPS convention for enumerators due to the possibility of clashing with macros. `NULL` in particular is one that annoys me when doing JSON stuff in C++.

Comment: Java did that one better, at least you don't need to qualify `EnumName::` in `switch` statements.

Answer (score 18):

So the short answer is no, but fortunately this is going to change in a recently finalized feature set of C++20. According to this [accepted proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1099r4.html) you will be able to do the following:

```
enum class CatState
{
    sleeping,
    napping,
    resting
};

std::string getPurr(CatState state)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        using enum CatState;
        // our states are accessible without the scope operator from now on

        case sleeping:      return {};      // instead of "case CatState::sleeping:"
        case napping:       return "purr";
        case resting:       return "purrrrrr";
    }
}
```

Comment: So glad this is in C++20! This makes scoped enums much more useful. PS: Put the using as low as possible, in this case inside the switch (see edit)

Answer (score 13):

You might consider using a `typedef` to shorten the qualified names:

```
typedef CatState C;
```

Or, if the columns are repetitive in a way that they can be generated easily, you might consider using a macro to generate each row in the table, which can lead to very concise (and easier to read) code.

Comment: So you're saying that there's no equivalent of `using namespace` for enums? If that's the case, then a short typedef seems like the best solution for me.

Comment: Not that I know of, no.  You may be able to use a using declaration for each enumerator (e.g., `using CatState::sleeping;`, etc.), but I'm not 100% sure.  If the code is highly repetitive, though, I'd strongly recommend a macro.

Comment: +1 I ended up using your typedef suggestion, but Nicol gave the direct answer to my question. I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: @James it is forbidden to use a using-declaration on scoped enumerators.

Comment: the typedef can also be spelled: `using C = CatState;`

Answer (score 4):

Nicol's answer is correct: the language is designed to make you always qualify scoped enumerators (except in the `enum { }` scope itself).

However, [here is a technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457058/a-way-to-use-all-the-unqualified-names-in-a-c0x-enum-class/7457908#7457908) I came up with for "scoped" enumerators that are unscoped within chosen classes. Technically, the enumerators are unscoped, so they will still convert implicitly to `int`. (Not "strongly-typed" as you put it.) Nevertheless, in the idiom they are accessed using the scope operator after a true `enum` name, so syntactically there isn't a difference — and therefore it requires C++11.

```
#define IMPORTABLE_ENUM( TYPENAME, ... ) \
\
struct import_ ## TYPENAME { \
    enum TYPENAME { \
        __VA_ARGS__ \
    }; \
}; \
\
typedef import_ ## TYPENAME :: TYPENAME TYPENAME;

// usage:
IMPORTABLE_ENUM ( duck, huey, dewey, louie )

duck d = duck::dewey; // can't use unscoped enumerators here

struct duck_madness : private import_duck { // but inside a derived class
    duck who_did_it() { return huey; } // qualification is unnecessary
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I would also love to have this possibility and I find the limitation quite annoying. It's usually best to have the programmer decide which features he wants to use. Either explicit scoping or the more convenient way. If you restrict the programmer he will either drop the whole feature for the sake of convenience or invent ugly workarounds, like the following template based type safe enum. It will have a some overhead when compiled without optimization.

```
template<class _Enum>
class type_safe_enum
{
private:
    _Enum m_EnumValue;
    operator int();
public:
    inline operator _Enum() const { return m_EnumValue; }
    inline void operator =(_Enum x) { m_EnumValue = x; }
};

enum _MY_ENUM
{
    Value1,
    Value2
};

enum _MY_ENUM2
{
    Value3,
    Value4
};

typedef type_safe_enum<_MY_ENUM> MY_ENUM;

void TestMyEnum()
{
    MY_ENUM myEnum;
    int x;

    myEnum = Value1; // ok
    // myEnum = Value3; // compilation error
    // myEnum = 0; // compilation error
    // x = myEnum; // compilation error

}
```

Comment: Your `_Enum` and other `_[A-Z]+` identifiers lead to undefined behavior, see [rules about underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/673852). Namely, `All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.`; `If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved<...>, the behavior is undefined.`.