# "using" directive for declarator of scoped enum?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, using, enum-class

Is there a way to use some kind of *using* directive to directly access members of an enum class type?

```
enum class Foo {
    Foo1,
    Foo2,
    ...
};

int main() {
    auto foo = Foo::Foo1;
    ??? // magic command to make the lines below work
    auto foo1 = Foo1;
    auto foo2 = Foo2;
    ...
}
```

I know I can do it with namespaces, so an alternative would be to use a namespace and a traditional enum:

```
namespace Foo {
    enum FooEnum {
        Foo1,
        Foo2,
        ...
    };
}

int main() {
    auto foo = Foo::Foo1;
    using namespace Foo;
    auto foo1 = Foo1;
    auto foo2 = Foo2;
    ...
}
```

However, I would like to keep the advantages of the class enums (like type safety, etc).

Comment: Wait... you say you want to use class enums, then why would you want to write the second line? You cannot even write `Foo foo2 = Foo2`, can you? So why would you expect it to work if you replace `Foo` by `auto`?

Comment: @CompuChip No, you're right. The question has nothing to do with auto, I also would like to make the line `Foo foo2 = Foo2` work with my magic line.

Comment: Jan, thanks, then I understand the question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450338/equivalent-of-using-namespace-x-for-scoped-enumerations

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Seems like I didn't look hard enough when searching my question, thanks :)