# Is is possible to make scoped enum identifiers driectly accessible in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

With C++ scoped enums, I have to write, for example:

```
enum class matrix_type_t { BINARY, INTEGER, REAL, COMPLEX };

std::string matrix_type_str(matrix_type_t type) {
   switch (type) {
      case matrix_type_t::BINARY:
         return std::string("binary");
      case matrix_type_t::INTEGER:
      ...
   }
}
```

However, if the context is clear, I would prefer:

```
std::string matrix_type_str(matrix_type_t type) {
   ??? // e.g. something as: using matrix_type_t::;
   switch (type) {
      case BINARY:
         return std::string("binary");
      case INTEGER:
      ...
   }
}
```

Is this possible to achieve somehow? If not, wouldn't it be worth considering for future C++?

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi Close, but I don't want to make aliases for all the enum identifiers, I would like to bring them all at once into the current scope.

Comment: I understand you. I don't know the answer, but according to that question, `using` won't help. Personally, I like the enums being scoped.

Comment: To chime in once more, [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450338/equivalent-of-using-namespace-x-for-scoped-enumerations) say that, indeed, it's not possible.

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi Thanks, haven't found that question under its name. I like scoped enums too, but avoiding to type their names would simplify my codes in some cases.